# send & receive UDP in a VST

Tags: c++, udp, vst

I have the foundation of my vsti in place and was wondering if anyones knows of some way to send and receive messages through UDP from inside the vst?

For example send incoming midi messages via UDP to a remote Synth(say kontakt) and then receive the output from that synth.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the answer that you're looking for, but you're approaching this problem the wrong way. :)

Sure, a VST plugin could embed a UDP host, and there are even networking libraries to help you do that. But then you'd need to write a virtual MIDI device which would forward those MIDI packets to your plugin via UDP, which is probably *way* too much work given the problem that you're trying to solve.

You're better off looking at how your sequencer (or the sequencers which you plan to support) handle MIDI routing, and see if you can route the MIDI data from the synth to your plugin. It shouldn't matter if you are writing an instrument or effect; the VST standard allows both types of plugins to receive MIDI data.